# Serializing SafeTransaction

Tags: gnosis-safe, string, safe-core-sdk, serialization

**How do I serialize `SafeTransaction` into a string and construct it from a string back to the instance with all data and signatures?**

Using the `safe-core-sdk`, how does one serialize `SafeTransaction` (result of [`safeSdk.createTransaction`](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-core-sdk#3-create-a-safe-transaction)) for storing in db or transport, so it can be passed to other signers? The [docs for off-chain signing](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-core-sdk#3a-off-chain-signatures) assumes that the distinct owners share memory and can pass along the `safeTransaction` instance object.

**Owner A**

```
const safeTransaction = await safeSdkA.createTransaction({ safeTransactionData })

// TODO: serialize safeTransaction to string to be stored in db or sent in HTTP request
const stringifiedData = safeTransaction.???
```

**Owner B (does not share memory with A, is seperate Node.js process)**

```
// TODO: create a valid SafeTransaction 
const safeTransaction = ???(stringifiedData)

const signedSafeTransaction = await safeSdkB.signTransaction(safeTransaction)

// TODO: serialize all data and signature
const stringifiedData = signedSafeTransaction.???
```

**Owner C (does not share memory with A or B)**

```
// TODO: create a valid SafeTransaction WITH SIGNATURES
const signedSafeTransaction = ???(stringifiedData)

const executeTxResponse = await safeSdkC.executeTransaction(safeTransaction)
await executeTxResponse.transactionResponse?.wait()
```

The constructor is only in internal [utils module](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/7f96a639082ea9552b8ea87e9970e6af225687e9/packages/safe-core-sdk/src/utils/transactions/SafeTransaction.ts#L11-L13) an d though there is a [method to encode signatures](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/7f96a639082ea9552b8ea87e9970e6af225687e9/packages/safe-core-sdk/src/utils/transactions/SafeTransaction.ts#L19-L31) to a string, there is no public API to decode them.

**Edit**
This snippet seems to work correctly, however it is fragile to any updates (relies on the structure, uses classes from non-public utils).

```
import { SafeTransaction } from "@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types";
import EthSignSignature from "@safe-global/safe-core-sdk/dist/src/utils/signatures/SafeSignature";
import EthSafeTransaction from "@safe-global/safe-core-sdk/dist/src/utils/transactions/SafeTransaction";

const safeTransactionToString = (safeTransaction: SafeTransaction) => {
    return JSON.stringify({
        signatures: [...safeTransaction.signatures.values()].map(s => ({signer: s.signer, data: s.data})),
        data: safeTransaction.data,
    })
}
const stringToSafeTransaction = (safeTransactionData: string): SafeTransaction => {
    const { signatures, data } = JSON.parse(safeTransactionData)
    const t = new EthSafeTransaction(data)
    for (const { signer, data } of signatures) {
        t.addSignature(new EthSignSignature(signer, data))
    }
    return t
}
```